# Windows Live Mail throwing Error ID 0x80048820 while Updating my E-Mail Account

Tags: windows-7, bios, time, windows-live-mail

*What Happened* :

I just switched on my PC in morning and I got CMOS diskette error(Dell Inspiron 530S), it just activates the floppy drive, so I switched it off from the *BIOS* in the next restart.

Later the date was also reset to year 2007 so I changed it and updated the time synchronizing with *time.window.com*

Now what happens is whenever am updating my accounts in Live Mail, it does update my Google Accounts but it throws me `Error ID 0x80048820` while updating Live account and it fails to synchronize...Any idea how do I fix this issue?

[image: Error Message Dialog Box]

Comment: Try changing the CMOS battery, set BIOS defaults, sync the time and then see what WLM does.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Microsoft Windows Live programs is trying to synchronize using Windows Time service. However this service was disabled as I was facing the same issue. Hence I did the following steps to sort out this issue; you could try this solution below:

Open WLM

1) Go to Run then type "services.msc" then press ENTER
2) Find "Windows Time" service then enable it and make sure the service is set to Startup Type to "automatic"
3) Go to Run then type "cmd" then press ENTER
4) Type the following command-line
w32tm /resync

You will get the result below:
Sending resync command to local computer
The command completed successfully.

5) Close Windows Live Mail then re-open it again, it will take approximately couple of miniutes to download & view all the emails.